# How to do a multi-level select field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As in my title mentioned I would like to have a select field where I can click on a option Item and then it shows me the suboptions. I only found solutions where you divide it in optgroups but then all the options are visible or I found something which is formatted.

My idea to solve this was the following:

**Html**

```
<select data-role="select" data-filter="false" v-on:change="boolValueChanger(testSelector)">
               <option value="testSelector">vegetable</option>
                   <optgroup v-if="testSelector" label="vegetable">
                       <option value="123123">pepper</option>
                       <option value="4565">spinach</option>
                       <option value="64734">broccoli</option>
                   </optgroup>

               <optgroup label="fruits">
                   <option value="43534">banana</option>
                   <option value="3345">apple</option>
                   <option value="45645">orange</option>
               </optgroup>
           </select>
```

**JS**

```
setup(props) {
            return {testSelector: ref(false) };
        },

        methods: {          
            boolValueChanger: function (x) {
                if (x === true) this.testSelector = false;
                else this.testSelector = true;
            }
        }
```

My idea was to make a "main menu" where I can select my optgroup (in my example that would be vegetable). If I select that the `testSelector` would be changed and the optgroups would display but unfortunately that didn't work. My example would be look ok but if I have like 200 options this would be look not so good anymore and a user would have to scroll a lot(I could use a search filter but if the options are unknown to the user this is also not nice).

Does anyone have an idea how I could realize something like that?

Comment: By "it shows me the suboptions", do you mean inside the same `<select>`?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, sorry if my description is misleading.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure. First of all, I don't think this is a good idea because it's not intuitive and doesn't work like people were taught how to use dropdowns for the last 30+ years. But if I had to implement this, I'd simply use two selects and hide the first and show the 2nd at the appropriate point in time.

Comment: @ChrisG But what would be the alternative, if I have a lot of unknown items which the user could select?

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly how you want this to work, but people commonly show multiple selects with all but the first being disabled, and when the user selects the first option, the 2nd select is activated, displaying new suboptions based on the 1st.

Comment: @ChrisG Okay, maybe I misused the selector. For  example I have things from a supermarket and these things are defined in different groups like fruits, vegetables, bread, juice... Each item-category in the subgroup has a Id-Nr (dont know if this is the right name for it). So that the category banana have its own Id-Nr. or apple-juice. But if I do a select for each of this groups this would be too much I think because all of them would be shown on the site (?). So I thought it would be the best to put it all in one dropdown

Comment: Well, can the user only select "banana" *or* "apple"? Because dropdowns are usually used to select from a bunch of exclusive options, like age groups. If this is supposed to be an ordering form, I'd group similar items but still show them all on the page, yes. (I'm also pretty sure you aren't supposed to have divs inside a select, only optgroups and options are valid afaik)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226048/discussion-between-lela-98-and-chris-g).